# Display observable after map

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to display a part of a list of item (pagination).
My template :

```html
<div class="notif" *ngFor="let notif of paginate() | async">
  {{notif.name}}
</div>
```

In my component if I do :

```js
public notifications: Observable<Notification[]>;
public paginate(): Observable<Notification[]> {
    return this.notifications;
  }
```

This is working, but if I do :

```js
public notifications: Observable<Notification[]>;
public paginate(): Observable<Notification[]> {
  return this.notifications.map((notif: Notification[]) => {
    return notif;
  });
```

It doesn't work anymore (I've simplified the function to understand what's going on).
.map retuns an observable right? So it should work both ways?

Comment: yap! it should work both the way, might be did some silly mistake and the observable part looks good

Comment: What is the error / behavior you are getting?

Comment: On first case i see the notification names, on the second case, nothing happen, nothing is shown on the page

Comment: I could not replicate this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpbufm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i think you're trying to map an array but you are using map on an Observable. That is why i suggested that you subscribe and then map the array into wtv you need and use the actual array from subscription

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong as you are trying to return a Notification[] in a function that returns an Observable of Notification[] so won't work.
If you need the Notification[] then you need to Subscribe to the Observable.

You cannot map an Observable into a different type.

e.g.

```
public paginate(): Observable<Notification[]> {
  return this.notifications;
  });


notificationArr: Notification[];

// This needs to be inside a method not in the class declaration of variables and methods
paginate().subscribe((notif: Notification[]) => {
return (this.notificationArr = notif);

  }); // should populate your array
```

Comment: dont forget to unsubscribe usually during ngOnDestroy()

Comment: .map() do returns an Observable, right? As they say here : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html My purpose here is to avoid notifications by using | async in the template. So I try to get just a part of my notification list, but still returns an observable. Isn't it possible with map(), or filter() ?

Comment: Since `async` is used we dont need to subscribe. moreover we cannot write statements inside class.

Comment: yes, as stated in comment above from Skeptor, if you intend to use the Observable in the DOM, then you don't need to subscribe to it to get the Notification[]. You can do something like for sure:  <div *ngFor=" let notif of paginate() | async"><!-- use the notif of type Notification inside interpolations --></div>.  So the only thing I saw wrong is your paginate() implementation, the rest looks fine.

Comment: Skeptor, I was trying to show the purpose and other possible ways without knowing much of the context  (whether the Observable was intended to be used in the DOM or inside the code as a Subscription) so wanted to show both options... and you are correct about  the code, it has to be inside a method body or smth, obviously not where we declare class attributes and methods..

Comment: Lempkin, did it work for you, it should, let us know otherwise and I can fine grain another example.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

Create a pipeline in order to use operators (map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, etc): https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer#pipe

```js
private _notifications = new BehaviorSubject<Notification[]>([]);
public notifications$ = this._notifications.pipe(
  // Returns original list. You can map this data however you want here.
  map(notifications => notifications)
);
```

```html
<div class="notif" *ngFor="let notif of (notifications$ | async)">
    {{notif.name}}
</div>
```